# How to group by substr on nth appereance of character

Tags: mysql

I've got a log table with lots of entries with some path info. 
I'm trying to group those log-tuples by path, and well by the first three slashes.
SO for instance:

```
1 /api/v1/endpoint/qwerty
2 /api/v1/endpoint/qwerty
3 /api/v1/endpoint/abcdef
.... etc etc
```

So I want to group them on /api/v1/endpoint/; so everything before the 4th (or better nth) slash.

How would my query look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function for this like

```
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(log_entry,'/',4)
```